# How to keep in the undo history just one change for this command?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement, cursor-motions, normal-mode, undo-redo

I want to keep in the undo history just one change for a long command such as: `d0kJx`. (I took the command from [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5282/5010).)

This command (`d0kJx`) does this (The `^` is the cursor position):

**Before:**

```
a bc def ghi
j k l mn o p q rs
      ^
```

**After:**

```
a bc def ghimn o p q rs
            ^
```

If this is possible, how can I do this? I think that maybe the answer is to extend the command in some way.

Thank you very much! `:-)`

Comment: For this specific command, it's worth noting that Karl's answer to your other question—`hvk$d`—is also undoable with a single `u`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are interested in `:h undo-blocks`.

To make the long command, e.g. `d0kJx`, undoable as a single change, you can run it from the command line through `normal`, e.g.:

```
:normal! d0kJx
```

Here the `!` ensures that we do not use custom mappings.